# NCurses read from stdin to std::string, C++

Tags: c++, string, stl, ncurses, stdstring

I'm writing a Linux app in which I must read a password from stdin using ncurses. I can read into a C-style string with no problem, however, this poses a security risk, so I must find a way to read into a STL string (std::string).
Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
initscr();
noecho();
string key;
... // Get the key from the user
string enter=key+"A"; // So the entered key is not the user-set one
while(enter!=key)
{
    const char* msg="Key to unlock terminal? ";
    move(y/2, (x-strlen(msg))/2);
    erase();
    printw(msg);
    sscanw("%s", enter); // How do I read into an STL string?
}
```

Comment: I doub't there any way to do that directly. I think you'll have to write a loop to read one character at a time and append each character to a std::string.

Comment: `ncurses` doesn't appear to support `std::string` at all, even in their C++ API.  The only references I can find to "string" in the source is including the C `string.h` header.

Comment: How does reading a password into a normal C-string pose a security risk?

Comment: It's supposed to lock the screen, like a UNIX, full-screen terminal, and should only be closed by entering the password, not by a buffer overflow or segfault caused by typing too many characters

Comment: @john, now that I think about it, I could use `getch()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too clear on `sscanw` but if the formatting work anything like `sscanf` I would suggest you limit the size of the input.

```
char[21] enter;
sscanw("%20s", enter);
enter[20] = 0;
```

The issue with security involves a buffer overflow (the user writes beyond the end of the buffer into program space). To solves this issue simple put a limit on the number of character(`%20s`) you read into the size of the buffer.